# Cannot resolve symbol in Java. I want to run the code of second class in the first class

Tags: java, email

I am learning Java from tutorials, and recently I faced with one problem. I need to create several classes, and I need to read all that classes through first class. Already I passed that tutorial where I understood everything and tried that thing. But now I want to create a real world app on Java, I did the exact thing which was showing in tutorial, but I am getting that error. Please, correct me where I have mistaken

Code of first class:

```
package com.company;

public class Email {


    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String department;
    private String alternateEmail;
    private int capacityMailbox;

    // Constructor to recieve the first name and last name
    public Email(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        System.out.println(em);
    }// Ask for the department

    // Generate a random password

    // Set the mailbox capacity

    // Set the alternate email

    // Change the password


}
```

Second one:

```
package com.company;

public class EmailApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Email em = new Email("John", "Smith");
    }
}
```

Screenshotes:

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: In the `Email` constructor, the `em` symbol doesn't refer to anything. That's a local variable in `EmailApp`. Just remove that last line from the `Email` constructor. You could put that line as an extra line in `EmailApp.main` instead, where the `em` variable is declared... *that* would make sense.

Comment: Better I will rewatch that tutorial, I guess it will make a lot of sense. Just I did not get fully what you and other wrote, I can not just copy it and paste.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.out.println(this)` in constructor. It means that you will print created instance to console. And also don't forget to override `toString()` method - because if you don't override it, you will get object's name with hashcode.

Hope this code will help you to reach the goal:

```
public class Email {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String department;
    private String alternateEmail;
    private int capacityMailbox;

    // Constructor to recieve the first name and last name
    public Email(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    // Ask for the department
    // Generate a random password
    // Set the mailbox capacity
    // Set the alternate email
    // Change the password

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Email{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

---

Another solution. Just override toString of Email class. And put printing of `em` to main method.

```
public class Email {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String department;
    private String alternateEmail;
    private int capacityMailbox;

    // Constructor to recieve the first name and last name
    public Email(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    // Ask for the department
    // Generate a random password
    // Set the mailbox capacity
    // Set the alternate email
    // Change the password

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Email{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class EmailApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Email em = new Email("John", "Smith");
        System.out.println(em);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your Email Class does not have a variable called `em`.
You should put `System.out.println(em)` into the Main method of your EmailApp class.

Answer (score 0):

The object reference "em" has no scope in first class i.e. class Email.

make these following two changes and compare your code. you will understand where you went wrong.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------change 1
  public Email(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
      
    }
```

and in second class:

```
//---------------------------------------------change 2
public class EmailApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Email em = new Email("John", "Smith");
        System.out.println(em.firstname);
        System.out.println(em.lastname);
    }
```

}

and make all member variables public for now. You will make it private when you understand "getters and setters" concept.

Comment: I did the second change, the ```System.out.println(em.firstname);
        System.out.println(em.lastname);``` painted red

Comment: make variables public* in first class @Ali